# Start SVN server after boot

Tags: linux, svn, centos7, svnserve

I have installed SVN 1.8 and I have created repository in `/var/svnrepos/svn/` directory. When I run SVN server with this command in terminal, everything work great and access from client to URL `svn://svnserver/svn/` is successfull:

```
svnserve -d -r /var/svnrepos/
```

I want the SVN server run at system startup. I added the command above into `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file. SVN server is running after boot, but when I access to server from client (TortoiseSVN), I get this message:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svnserver/svn'
Can't open file '/var/svnrepos/svn/format': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: In `systemd` case you'll need to install enable the relevant service instead: [Services and Daemons](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Services_and_Daemons.html)
Executing `rc.local` might need to be installed as a service itself or even if it is executed you might be trying to start svn service with an incorrect user.

---

Isn't SVN started with `/etc/init.d/svnserve`? **EDIT**: No because `systemd` is used instead, making the below relevant for earlier versions only

in which case you can create aliases to that script to start it in the relevant `/etc/rc<runlevel>.d/` dirs. Or with 
[update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) if available.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but `/etc/init.d/svnserve` script does not exist.

Comment: CentOS 7 uses systemd, there will not be an init script

Comment: D'oh didn't see the tag! Well, good luck with systemd my friends.

Comment: I found this topic on the SVN forum and it works perfectlly!
[goo.gl/BHjDtw](http://goo.gl/BHjDtw)